# Pop-up & Sticky Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

```
<div class="popupstick">
<p> Hlasujte v anketě "Čtenáři Receptáře doporučují" a <ins> 
<a href="http://www.ireceptar.cz/">získejte ZDARMA Edici Receptáře &gt;&gt;</a></ins>
<button class="close-stick" title="Close" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('popupstick').style.display='none';setCookie('hideModal', '2', 7) ;">x</button>
</div>
<!-- POP UP  -->
<div id="overlay">
<div class="popupstick2">
    <img src="img/anketa-overlay.png" alt="overlay">
    <button class="close-popup" title="Close" onclick="document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='none';setCookie('hideModal', '1', 7 ) ;"></button>
```

Ребят может мне кто нибудь объяснить почему в первом button'e неработает функция закрытия, а во втором работает? И как эт возможно исправить?

Comment: Прочитайте, пожалуйста, как создать: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже было замечено в комментарии - пожалуйста, сопровождайте подобные вопросы [минимальным, самодостаточным и воспроизводимым примером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Без этого поиск ответа включает в себя владение телепатией.

Тем не менее, мне кажется, я вижу проблему:

вы используете `document.getElementsByClassName('popupstick').style.display='none'` и забываете о том, что функция getElement**s**ByClassName возвращает массив элементов. У массива нет свойства `[].style`. Скорее всего, нажатие на эту кнопку выплевывает в консоль ошибку.

Вам нужно обратиться к конкретному элементу из массива, который возвращает функция `document.getElementsByClassName('popupstick')`. Если у вас гарантированно один элемент с таким классом - можно просто обратиться к нулевому элементу (`document.getElementsByClassName('popupstick')[0]`). Если элементов неизвестное количество - придется перебирать циклом и выполнять действие над каждым элементом по очереди.

В итоге, код должен выглядеть таким образом (если у вас один блок с классом `popupstick`):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('popupstick')[0].style.display='none';
```

Comment: Понял, в следуйщий раз учту.
Большое спасибо!